# What are the pros and cons of using Meteor-Roles?

Tags: javascript, meteor, roles

I'm looking to make an app where there is an admin account that can manage all the other user's profiles. My question is, what are  the pros of using Meteor-Roles? I watched a video on youtube about it and looked through the documentation, it seems to use pub/sub and on Create to add a field named "role:". Do I actually need this package? It seems like Meteor's built-in pub/sub and oncreate function are simple and enough to accomplish this feature?

Answer (score 3):

You could roll your own (bad pun intended, sorry), but why? The source code is available: [meteor-roles](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles) .

When you decide you need it, then add it. If you don't think you need it yet, then don't add it yet.

I use it to apply an "admin" role to certain users, and a "blocked" role to others which prevents them logging in. The package gives you some handy functions to add roles to users, or check to see if a user has a role. It can also be very handy for finer-level control over publications (e.g. some users might have read-only access, whereas users with a certain role might have read-write access).